# fix css responsive error on mobile navigation iphone

Tags: css, responsive

i want solve small error view in css on iphone, in this moment logo and login links is wrong view on my iphone, screen :
[actual iphone view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tADtI.jpg)

i want to solve this, like this :

http://jmp.sh/MbG6Al4

how i can do this ? the url of my website is : selfmarket.net

Comment: The issue lies with your use of floats, you need to either clear them or change them to get this working correctly.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve] A link to your web site is not acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**.header_area**:

- Remove `overflow: hidden;`
- Remove the image inside `.header_area`

**.header_over_content**

- Apply  `background-image: url('/static/images/landing/hm_header_bg.jpg');`
- Give it a `height: 360px;`
- Replace the `position: absolute;` with `position: relative;`

**.hdr_bnr_content**

- Give it a `background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);`

**.logo**

- Replace `padding-left: 20px;` with `padding: 0;`